# Is there a way to create Folders to organize Documents-AWS Systems Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

Is there a way to create Folders to organize Documents-AWS Systems Manager? I have a bunch of documents but I see no way of organizing them and don't see a way to create folders. Let me know if there is a way to organize them. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply from AWS forums- no folder structure present in UI- use tags if needed